# How to accumulate text cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Is it possible in Excel 2010 to have a function that finds duplicates in a column range and based on the number of duplicates, then accumulates the equal range into one cell?

This is how my data looks:

```
Family  Name       Age    Postcode  
Doe     John       40      1400
Doe     Jane       35      1400
Doe     Baby       5       1400
Mark    Peter      14      1600
Matt    Simon      25      1700
Matt    Paul       14      1700
```

And I would like the output to look like this:

```
Family Name [Member/age]                [Postcode]
Doe    John [John/40, Jane/35, Baby/5]   1400
Mark   Peter[Peter/14]                   1600
Matt   Simon[Simon/25, Paul/14]          1700
```

Comment: I don't understand the data and what you hope to get from it. Have you considered using pivot tables based on some 'helper cells' to combine the Family, Name, Age and Postcode cells in the format you want?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it will involve an array function.

You might be able to find something useful at:
http://www.get-digital-help.com/category/excel/searchlookup/

maybe:
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/11/29/lookup-and-return-multiple-values-from-a-range-excluding-blanks/

or:
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/03/28/search-for-a-text-string-and-return-multiple-adjacent-values/

I don't know if you'll be able to format it exactly the way you're showing but you might be able to at least achieve so results.